# Where can I post questions for back-end developers?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I don't know what to do, I have tried to find the right site but all my posts get blocked all the time.

I want to ask for help concerning my website project. I want to know if I actually need a back-end developer for a website I built, and if so, how I can proceed in finding the right one.

Where do I ask something like this? I tried Webmasters, Programmers, and Server Fault...

Comment: If you are looking for someone to hire, non of the Stack Exchanges are suitable. You can look at the Stack Overflow [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) site for that.

Comment: Hi Lisa, I think almost all the Q&A sites that are part of StackExchange are about a specific topic only, and are not places to get answers from a specific type of person about any topic at all. Your best bet would probably be to ask in one of the chat rooms for the related sites, however I think you need a bit of reputation on the site to chat so that may not work for you. You may also be able to find the answer to part of your question here: [How to Determine # of Programmers needed for a project](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/132580/1130)

Comment: I don't follow. Either you, yourself, know how to build what you need, or you don't. If you don't, then either you, yourself, are game for learning how to build it, or you're not. If you've never programmed before, then the answer is 'you need a dev' unless you are prepared to take a multi-month side trip into learning to program.

Answer (score 1):

You could try here maybe:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer

You would need to be sure that you need a developer first however (full-time as George has stated in his answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to look elsewhere. If someone has their contact info on their profile, you could risk asking them to help you; but there's no official place to ask for developers on Stack Overflow or any other site.

If you want to hire someone as a Full time employee, then it's likely you could try [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com), but if you're looking for a free-lancer, this suite of sites is not a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be in the right place judging by some of your questions, it's just some of your thoughts need a little more thinking, consider reading http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html to get an idea of how to scope your questions.

Most SE sites tend to steer away from open ended questions asking for best/opinion/ideas.

There are also many questions that answer your questions, it's just a matter of searching using Stack Overflow or Google (`site:stackoverflow.com "query"`)

*So you want to know how to build a site like X?*

Start reading about the technologies behind it.

E.g. Stack Overflow [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

From there you chunk down into the various languages and tools and so on

To be more specific, say this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188393/html-css-php-javascript-sql

This question needs to be broken into two questions, one for e-commerce and one for gaming. Then chunk down again to a specific language. The chunk down again to your doubts behind the security of X feature in Y language, and then chunk down again until you have developed a near perfectly scoped question for us to read, vote up and answer.